# Импорт класса из файла в основную программу

Tags: python, импорт, модули

создал в отдельном файле класс и хочу его импортировать в основную программу, но мне выдает ошибкy: cannot import name 'game' from 'Games'

это откуда я импортирую:

```
class Games:
  def game(message, call):
```

это я написал в основном файле, в самом начале:

```
from Games import game
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас вы импортируете функцию с `game`. А нужно импортировать класс, то есть шаблон будет такой `from <имя файла> import <имя класса>`.

---

Если файл лежит в отдельной папке то следует указывать также и имя папки через точку `from <имя папки>.<имя файла> import <имя класса>`

Comment: вот теперь получилось, но вот хочу вызвать эту функцию game, но пишет: name 'game' is not defined. Как правильно вызвать функцию и что именно нужно вызвать из файла, класс или функцию?

Comment: Вам нужно создать объект класса и из него вызывать функцию [Первая ссылка в поисковике](https://python-scripts.com/python-class). Если ответ вас устраивает, то нужно его принять, делается это с помощью галочки слева.

Comment: я походу чайник и не понял, что нужно сделать, чтобы убрать новую ошибку, которую я написал чуть выше

Comment: @Loverツ по ссылке есть примеры кода, как вызывать функции из классов. А вообще вам бы ознакомиться с **ООП**.

Comment: я не знаю что такое ООП, но я перечитаю снова ту статью.

Comment: Так впишите данную аббревиатуру в используемый вами поисковик.

Comment: просидел очень много времени, но так и не понял, буду долго разбираться...